# Using CASE under ORDER BY clause in SQL

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by, case

Write a SQL query to find all the details of 1970 winners by the ordered to subject and winner name; but the list contain the subject Economics and Chemistry at last.

```
SELECT *
FROM nobel_win
WHERE year=1970 
ORDER BY
 CASE
    WHEN subject IN ('Economics','Chemistry') THEN 1 //what does 1 mean?
    ELSE 0 //what does 0 mean
 END ASC,
 subject,
 winner;
```

Comment: CASE *expression*.

Answer (score 2):

The `case` expression returns 1 is the subject is Economics or Chemistry and 0 otherwise. This means that rows with those subjects will get sorted **after** all the other rows.

Comment: I understood that it returns 1, but what does the ASC after the END do?

Comment: @tru `asc` is short for "**asc**ending order", so that the 0s are sorted before the 1s. It can be omitted since this is the default behavior for an `order by` term